# Retrolambda and web applications

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, retrolambda

I'd like to use lambda expressions offered by Java 8. However, I'm restricted to JRE 6. I know that retrolambda can do a backporting of code. But, is it possible to use retrolambda for a web application (.war)? Actually, I'd like to write code making use of lambda expression, using my Eclipse Neon for developing a web application that must run on a Tomcat 6. So, could retrolambda (or another thing) help me in this task?